# [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbca.so' : file not found

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, odbc, unixodbc

I have installed Postgresql 9.4 on Ubuntu 16.04, and installed postgresql ODBC and Unix ODBC drivers. When I test the ODBC connection with isql it works fine. Also, I am able to connect to the databases using pgadmin III from local and remote locations.

[image: pdAdmin III]

[image: isql]

But, when I am trying to install a software which will create a connection using ODBC I am getting the following error

> Connect failed!
>
> Error code = -1
> Status from database system is:  STATE=01000, CODE=0, MSG=[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbca.so' : file not found
> ERROR(-1)

But the library actually exists in this location. Please advise. I have attached the odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini for your reference.

```
file: /etc/odbc.ini

[PostgreSQL_DCTM]
Description=PostgreSQL DCTM
Driver=PostgreSQL_ANSI
Trace=No
TraceFile=/tmp/psqlodbc.log
Database=dctmdev
Servername=localhost
UserName=dctmdbadmin
Password=*******
Port=5432
Protocol=7.4-2
ReadOnly=No
RowVersioning=No
ShowSystemTables=No
ShowOidColumn=No
FakeOidIndex=No
UpdateableCursors=Yes
ConnSettings=
DEBUG=Yes

file: /etc/odbcinst.ini

[PostgreSQL_ANSI]
Description=PostgreSQL ODBC driver (ANSI version)
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbca.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcpsqlS.so
Debug=0
CommLog=1
UsageCount=2

[PostgreSQL_Unicode]
Description=PostgreSQL ODBC driver (Unicode version)
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbcw.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcpsqlS.so
Debug=0
CommLog=1
UsageCount=2
```

[image: Content of folder '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbca.so']

Your help is much appreciated!

```
Update - 08/01/2018

/documentum/product/7.3/install/Server_Configuration_Program.bin: POSIX shell script executable (binary data) 

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbca.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=e76dd2bbea2b741a14671866f35468af7c62acbb, stripped 

The version of the psqlodbca.so is shown as 'stripped'. However, in the documentation of the software that I am trying to install it mentions to use 'not stripped' version. Could you please help me understand how could I procure the 'not stripped' version of the client library?
```

Comment: Is your new tool 32-bit or 64-bit? Check with `file <executable>`, like `file isql`. Also double-check `file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbca.so` (which *should* show 64-bit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the packaged libraries in the software that I was using to communicate to the database. After removing liblber-2.4.so.2 from the software lib, this started working.

For your reference, if any of you out there, is facing same problem while installing Opentext Documentum 7.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 and PostgreSQL 9.4, you might be hitting the same issue.